# How to select a text in a textView having a NSRange in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsrange, selectedtext

I have a `UITextView` where I would like to select a part of the text. I'm trying to use `selectedTextRange`, unfortunately I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected
>   argument type 'UITextRange'

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
mainTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
mainTextField.selectedTextRange = mainTextField.textInRange(matchRange) // matchRange is a NSRange
```

The range I'm using is coming from a Regex which I adapted from [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial)[1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial):

EDIT: added the first line

```
if let regex =  NSRegularExpression(options: searchOptions){ // refers to an installed extension convenience init
let range = NSMakeRange(0, (mainTextField.text.characters.count))
let matches = regex.matchesInString(mainTextField.text, options: [], range: range)
[...]
```

Comment: Please share the declaration of your `regex` variable too

Comment: Thank you  Victor Sigler, I added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an extension on `UITextView` that will do the conversion.

```
    extension UITextView
    {
        func textRangeFromNSRange(range:NSRange) -> UITextRange?
        {
            let beginning = self.beginningOfDocument
            guard let start = self.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: range.location), end = self.positionFromPosition(start, offset: range.length) else { return nil}

            return self.textRangeFromPosition(start, toPosition: end)
        }
    }
```

Use

```
    if let range = mainTextView.textRangeFromNSRange(range: matchRange){
        mainTextField.selectedTextRange = range
    }
```

Where `matchRange` is an `NSRange` and `range` is a `UITextRange`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 updated version of [@beyowulf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932536/7515957):

```
extension UITextView {

    func textRangeFromNSRange(range:NSRange) -> UITextRange? {
        let beginning = beginningOfDocument
        guard let start = position(from: beginning, offset: range.location), let end = position(from: start, offset: range.length) else { return nil }

        return textRange(from: start, to: end)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add a little more information, I found also an alternative way: instead of using selectedTextRange and doing the conversion, you can use selectedRange.

Note: matchRange is a NSRange

```
// this don't work because selectedTextRange requires an UITextRange
textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textInRange(matchRange) // don't work

// this works because selectedRange requires a NSRange
textField.selectedRange = matchRange // works
```